# How to read and save BIOS from GeForce GT630M to change throttle temperature in Acer V3

Tags: graphics-card, bios, nvidia-graphics-card, acer-aspire, throttling

**ORIGINAL POST Please skip to EDIT**

Hello I am using the Acer V3-571G which has set GPU throttling temperature to really low value(lower than other manufacturers) it makes GPU useless it throttles immedeatly(computer is clean almost new), I know the risk...etc. **but straight to the point.**a

I have tried to read GPU BIOS by GPU-Z and then change throttle temperature by NiBiToR but GPU-Z cannot read the BIOS it says that file `...Local\Temp\\nvflash.rom cannot` be find. This file really exists on my computer but on the location :`...Local\Temp\nvflash.rom` This double slashes in GPU-Z makes this path corrupted in my opinion.

How to fix that and read that .rom file correctly.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have been thinking about other possible solutions beside changing throttle temperature. And I decided to not change throttle temperature but change throttle GPU Clock Frequency.
I have used nVidia Inspector which allows to read the graphics card performance profiles. 
I wanted change minimum allowed GPU Clock frequency but it is not possible, it is blocked and this programm do not allow to change it, but maybe you know other way to overwrite graphics card profile.

PS: Unlock min just changes the displayed GPU Clock range not from 270 but from 0mHZ.

[image]

Comment: You could try the leaked [FERMI BIOS EDITOR](http://www.overclock.net/t/989627/fermi-bios-editor-gtx-4-5-series), but I take no responsibility.